# Binary compatiblity between VS 2010 and VS 2010 SP1 C++ binaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am contemplating installing SP1 for VS 2010. Are binaries compiled using VS 2010 and VS 2010 SP1 binary compatible? Or does it introduce yet another version/assembly of MSVCR100 and MSVCP100?

Comment: When you install the service pack you will get the runtime DLLs to your workstation. When you distribute you should provide an installer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be YES binaries are compatible, atleast between VS2010 and VS2010 SP1.
And here is a [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/03/02/stuff-from-the-road-binary-compatibility.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20zainnab%20%28Visual%20Studio%20Tips%20and%20Tricks%29) saying so.
Note: I googled it out of curiosity :)

Comment: I've been afraid to update the VS 2010 redestributables in my product prior to discovering this. Thank you.